# Pumping water into IndustrialCraft2 machines

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm currently working on a game that I've setup with [FTB Beyond](https://www.feed-the-beast.com/projects/ftb-beyond). As I'm used to playing with buildcraft installed, I can't seem to find a way of pumping water into various IC2 machines, such as the [Ore Washing Plant](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Ore_Washing_Plant). I've tried adding a pump from thermal expansion and connected it to the Ore Washing Plant via TE pipes, but with no result. And as far as I can see, there's no native IC2-way of piping in water to the machines.

So my question boils down to: How does one automatically supply IC2 machines with water from a pond a few blocks away? Using any gear available via FTB, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a setup I just did using the latest version of the pack in creative mode:

[image]

You can see it being powered by a bat box, with water being pumped in using fluid ducts from an Aqueous Accumulator (which is powered by a creative capacitor under it).

As you can see, it's full:

[image]

And here we've got it essentially the same way, except using a pressurized fluid conduit from Ender IO:

[image]

So the quick-n-cheap route is just use the pump (accumulator) from Thermal Expansion along with the (rather cheap) fluid ducts, if you want to get fancy then you can use other options.

I miss BC too, especially the pump, as it's so versatile. But TE has you covered.

Answer (score 0):

IC2 Machines have directional inputs, that allow you to automatically move items through a system. A simple example would be Macerator > Electric Furnace. However, to move the items from one to the other, they need to be pulled out of one *specific* side from the Macerator, and the pumped into a *specific* side of the Furnace.

The same is true for the Ore Washing Plant. Basically, with the use of pumps and pipes, you can make sure that your Ore Washing Plant is perpetually filled with water.

This [video](https://youtu.be/dZc9El0h3yQ?t=5m26s) shows this in more detail.

Comment: I know about buildcraft, as I've used that a lot in Tekkit, unfortunately BC is not part of FTB Beyond, so I have to find a different way. Fluid pipe from Emersive Engineering does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Jarmund What about Thermal Expansion? The have a [FluidDuct](https://ftbwiki.org/Fluiduct) that may do the trick